# Expected a module declaration, found something else?

Tags: racket

I'm working on a Racket script (on a Linux machine) that requires the math/number-theory library.  My entire script at the moment is thus:

```
#!/usr/bin/racket

(require math/number-theory)
```

Yes, it's literally just requiring the library.

When I try to run it, I get an error that reads "expected a `module' declaration found: something else".

However, when I actually start up Racket in the terminal like so:

```
/usr/bin/racket
```

and enter (require math/number-theory) in the command line, it treats it like it's totally valid.

What's going on here?

Comment: The difference between a program and the REPL. Try adding an expression (like #f) after require.

Comment: I did that; it didn't help at all.

Comment: You need `#lang racket` at the top, just underneath the shebang.

Comment: Alexis has the right answer, but also see the [Unix scripts](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/scripts.html#%28part._.Unix_.Scripts%29) section of the Guide which has a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 24):

Make sure the top of your racket files contains a `#lang` statement as well.

In other words, you need this at the top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/racket
#lang racket
```